# How to apply an action on disabled button press in react native elements Button component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, validation, react-native-elements

Let's say there is a form with an input. The submit button is disabled until there is an input in the input element.

When the user enters the input, the submit button is enabled and the user can easily submit the form. But in case when there is no input and the user press the disabled submit button, the `onDisabledPress()` handler should be taken into action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just about your logic there is no need for external function. You will need a state to tell the button the way it should render, I called it is `submitable`. When `submitable` is true, the button  will have active style, and when false it should use disabled style. For example:

```js
const submitable = state.formInput1.length > 0 && state.formInput2.length > 0;

return (
   <TouchableOpacity
      style={submitable ? styles.active : styles.disabled}
      onPress={()=> {
         if (submitable) {
            console.log("Success")
         } else {
            console.log("You must input all required field")
         }
      }}
   ><Text>Submit</Text></TouchableOpacity>
)

const styles = {
   active: {
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
   },
   disabled: {
      backgroundColor: 'gray',
      opacity: 0.5,
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `Disabled` means no action can take place on the button or no event will be triggered for a disabled button.

What I can understand from your use case is that, you want the button to look like a disabled button and when the user passes the button instead of `onPress`  `onDisabledPress` function should be called.

The only possible way of doing that is  below.

1. Keep a flag that holds the disabled state of the button say `buttonDisabled`
2. Based on the the above flag apply the CSS styling to the button that makes it look like a disabled button (e.g greyed out)
3. When this button is pressed the `onPress` even handler will be called. Add this below piece of code to that handle

```
    onPressHandler(){
    // make sure below lines are the first lines to execute in the onPressHandler
    if(this.state.buttonDisabled){
       this.onDisabledPress();
       return;
    }
    }
    onDisabledPress(){
     // disabled handler
    }
```

This will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there is a event in react native which you can fire even when touch is disabled.

It is used as

```js
   onTouchStart={() => {
            console.log('yoo, button is touched');
     }}
```